# Not able to create src and public folder using npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs

I tried all things means all commands are still is not able to create react app please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean you can not create folders? just create them in your file explorer / manager

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

update your node version. Try uninstalling then reinstall